# Can I set data to DefaultCategoryDataset in jfree from map or arraylist

Tags: java

usually we have to add  values manually to dataset using addValue as given below,

```
 DefaultCategoryDataset dataset =new DefaultCategoryDataset( );     
         dataset.addValue( 1.0 , fiat , speed );        
          dataset.addValue( 3.0 , fiat , userrating );        
          dataset.addValue( 5.0 , fiat , millage ); 
          dataset.addValue( 5.0 , fiat , safety; )
```

is there any other methods to create dataset with the help of arraylist or hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some examples:[Examples](http://www.javased.com/?api=org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset)

Or if you mean you wanna use a list to auto add values:

```
 static class Customer{
    String name;
    int salary;
    int age;

    public Customer(String name, int salary, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Customer> data = new ArrayList<Customer>(){{add(new Customer("x",100,20));add(
    new Customer("y",200,30));add(new Customer("z",300,40));}};
    for(Customer c:data){
        System.out.println(c.name+" _ "+c.salary+" - "+c.age);
    }

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    for(Customer c :data){
        dataset.addValue(c.salary, "low", "");
    }

     //Cont'd other JFreechart codes ...


}
```

If you use Java, and try to do thing like:`DefaultCategoryDataset list = new Arraylist<>()`It's impossible. Because DefaultCategoryDataset([DefaultCategoryDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html)) is extentded from AbstracDataset and implements Serializable(java.io.Serializable).There is no way to use arraylist and hashmap.

```
protected AbstractDataset() {
    this.group = new DatasetGroup();
    this.listenerList = new EventListenerList();
    this.notify = true;
}
```